# Joomla error uploading hand-coded template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I'm trying to upload my hand-coded template to Joomla 2.5.

I have moved it to the templates folder online. Now I'm trying to INSTALL it from Extension Manager > Install (I see the path to it in the textbox against the Install button). But upon clicking the button, I get this error:

> -1 - An error has occurred.
>
> Copy failed

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="template">
    <name>Travels</name>
    <description>
        Template for Target Travels
    </description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>catergory.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        <filename>css/template.css</filename>  
        <filename>css/mystyle.css</filename>  
        <filename>css/common.css</filename>  
        <filename>css/crasel.css</filename>  
        <filename>css/jquery.jcarousel.css</filename>  
        <filename>css/skin.css</filename>
        <folder>css</folder>  
        <folder>images</folder>
    </files>
    <positions>  
        <position>breadcrumb</position>  
        <position>welcome</position>  
        <position>tour_catergory</position>  
        <position>left</position>  
        <position>right</position>  
        <position>top</position>  
        <position>user1</position>  
        <position>user4</position>  
        <position>footer</position>  
    </positions>
</extension>
```

Any idea on the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to permission issues with folders. In the Joomla backend go to:

**Site** (top menu) >> **System Information** >> **Directory Permissions** and ensure the "*templates*" folder is writable. Whilst you're at it, ensure all folder and files in the list are writable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes the templates folder and it's contents are writable but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If your template is already in place you should use discover install not install from directory. You have no need to copy files if the files are already where they need to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using Discover gives me **No extensions have been discovered. Click Discover to find new extensions that might be available for install.* And it's not even showing in the list of templates. I think I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

Comment: If you have the template in the templates folder and you click Discover it should find it assuming it is complete including the xml file.  Look at one of the core templates and make sure that your xml is set up just like those but with your template name.  It's not going to show in the list of templates if it isn't installed, the list only shows installed templates and then the template styles.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, I couldn't upload the zip file. It reported some error or the other. My folders have 755 permissions so it's not an issue of permissions. Even physically moving the zip and installing did not create the css and images folders of my template. So I manualy dragged the folder structure and this seemed to have worked to some sort. So I presume this is an issue wiht joomla. Thanks again!

Comment: You would never upload a zip file as a zip file. If you have it as a zip then you would use upload and install.